# Load bearing wall removal

Tags: walls, load-bearing, removal

Looking to remove a portion of the wall the leads into our garage to extend our dining area.

The wall sits ontop of the block foundation but parallel to the roof joists on a hip roof [image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smTjw.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The wall to the right of the door with the yard tools hanging on it?

Comment: all exterior walls under a hip roof are load bearing.  The ones parallel to the joists are less important.  Does the door on that wall have a header?

Comment: Correct, basically everything from the left side of the door to the exterior wall. I will be pulling off the osb of that side of the wall to check on current framing but unsure currently.